# Telling TFS 2010 Build to use SDK 7.1 

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, winapi

I have installed TFS 2010 including Build Service on a Win Srv 2008 R2 machine, and it works - almost.

What I can't seem to get going is the build using tools like `resgen.exe` from the Windows SDK - I get an error:

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (1835):
>   Task could not find "Resgen.exe" using the SdkToolsPath
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\" or the
>   registry key
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0A". Make sure the
>   SdkToolsPath is set and the tool
>   exists in the correct processor
>   specific location under the
>   SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft
>   Windows SDK is installed

OK, so I went and downloaded and installed the most recent Windows SDK - v7.1. Everything went fine, I now have a copy of `resgen.exe` present and all - but I am still getting the same error.

OK, so I went and inspected the MSBuild targets file (`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets`) mentioned in the error message - and I see it's using lots of references to `FrameworkSDKDir` and  `_TargetFrameworkSDKDirectoryItem` - but where are those values initially set (to an obviously wrong directory, in my case) ?? I can't seem to find the "core" targets file and tell it to use my `\SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin` directory (instead of the `\SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin` it wants to find - there's nothing in there...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the real problem is integration of [the SDK v7.1 with VS2010](http://geekswithblogs.net/rob/archive/2010/09/17/integrate-the-windows-sdk-v7.1-with-vs2010.aspx).